# AWS S3 access denied with Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload files on Amazon S3, but it returns this error :

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 26B9B4844CEA580C), S3 Extended Request ID: S0Ds3cvubCSZTAd1ESUG5rMRifGLHRAHBviyUHzDVI5W8FQxtRDMBNSrhVme6K86UryWxqORv30=
```

I have already configured IAM and the bucket on AWS and I use the good access/secret (the one aws gave me). What's the problem? Thank you!

**S3Client Code:**

```
s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withRegion(Regions.CA_CENTRAL_1) // The first region to try your request against
    .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true) // If a bucket is in a different region, try again in the correct region
    .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
    .build()
```

**Upload file code:**

```
private fun uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName: String, file: File) {
    s3client.putObject(PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file)
        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead))
  }
```

**IAM user :**

[image]

**S3 permissions :**
[image]

Comment: Is there a Bucket Policy assigned to the bucket?

Comment: No I'm new on AWS, should I add something?

Comment: No, but that's what you should have shown for your bucket permissions screenshot. If there is no bucket policy, then it looks like you aren't setting the correct values for access key or secret key, or you aren't setting the correct bucket name in the code.

Comment: best practice to manage access to objects is using S3 policies, not individual object ACL, as you could manage access to whole set of objects at once and not configure ACL for each object individually. As well the `blocking public access` attribute may block the call to.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I made it work disabling the first option

**Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)**

If you want to get more information about the default Canned ACL, here is a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl_overview.html#canned-acl)

If you don't want to disable any of these policies you can use pre signed urls

You can see examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)